# SQL Server 2008 R2 (64-bits) - Service Pack 2 - UC5 can't find Adobe's iFilter 11.0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ifilter

I am getting the following error when rebuilding a catalog containing a table with a stored PDF (it does work for Word documents).

> Warning: No appropriate filter was found during full-text index
>   population for table or indexed view '[Test].[dbo].[Table_1]' (table
>   or indexed view ID '2105058535', database ID '6'), full-text key value
>   '911'. Some columns of the row were not indexed.

I followed the installation procedures from Adobe and ran the following commands:

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_service @action='load_os_resources', @value=1; -- update os resources 
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'verify_signature', 0 -- don't verify signatures 
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'update_languages'; -- update language list 
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts'; -- restart daemon 
EXEC sp_help_fulltext_system_components 'filter'; -- view active filters
```

The last does return the correct filter path:

```
filter .pdf E8978DA6-047F-4E3D-9C78-CDBE46041603 C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe PDF iFilter 11 for 64-bit platforms\bin\PDFFilter.dll 11.0.1.36 Adobe Systems, Inc.
```

I have added the path to `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe PDF iFilter 11 for 64-bit platforms\bin\` and verified that it works.

I have re-started the services (even rebooted the machine). I also I verified by running the filtdump.exe that comes with the Windows SDK to verify that the filter does work OUTSIDE of SQL Server 2008 R2.

Also I have re-configured the sql server services so they run with an admin account (in case the problem is related to permissions).

Lastly, I have tried on several machines (some running with the SP1) and same result. No problems registering the DLL... SQL Server simply does not call the filter. Note that I have tried uploading a document to the same table with an "unknown" extension (e.g. ".xyz") and I get the same result... It is like if ".pdf" was an extension not registered (however it is).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into all kinds of weird problems when trying to solve this issue.  The solution was to grant adobe iFilter dll bin directory full access to the SQL Server database engine service account.

My tests where done with Adobe 9.0.   We tried first Adobe Pdf 11 filter with no luck, reinstalled Adobe Pdf 9, no luck, reinstalled SQL Server 2008r2 + sp2 + Adobe Pdf no luck.

I rebuilt catalogs, not working.  Finally as you commented about possibility that SQL Server was simply not calling the Dll, I suspect an access permission problem. By granting above permissions it worked.

Maybe this would make Adobe PDF 11 work, but beware of correcting the path for version 11.